# How to separate a String line with a paragraph to make text as a list

Tags: java, string

I have a really long text that looks like "123testes1233iambeginnerplshelp123 .." and I need to separate the line with the paragraph each time the program reads number.
So output should be like:

123tests
12333iambeninnerplshelp
123 ...

Comment: welcome. you should complete your question with *"...and I tried doing <what your attempt has been>..."* so that people here can further guide you in correct direction.

Answer (score 4):

You can solve it using Regex. Everytime we are looking for patterns where number is followed by characters and if it is found, print it:

```
        String text = "123testes1233stackoverflowwillsaveyou123dontworry";
        String wordToFind = "\\d+[a-z]+";
        Pattern word = Pattern.compile(wordToFind);
        Matcher match = word.matcher(text);

        while (match.find()) {
            System.out.println(match.group());
        }
```

Comment: Why do you use `start()` and `end()` ? That is not enough :         `while (match.find()) {
            System.out.println(match.group());
        }` ?

Answer (score 2):

One way to do it would be to use [`StringTokenizer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html). If you make the assumption that every output line must start with `123`, even if the input doesn't start with it, it could be:

```
String input = "123testes1233iambeginnerplshelp123 ..";
String delimiter = "123";
StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(input, delimiter);
while (tokenizer.hasMoreTokens()) {
  String line = delimiter + tokenizer.nextToken();
  System.out.println(line);
}
```

Comment: I think the OP wants any number, not a static delimiter. Is there a streamed solution that provides a delegate (Predicate) type as an argument instead of the const String that is similar to StringTokenizer?

Comment: @PaulNikonowicz If it were any number, the string would be 1, 2, 3tests, etc instead of 123tests

Comment: @PaulNikonowicz you got it right. Sorry not to mention it

Answer (score 1):

A simple approach (without any dependencies) would look something like this,

```
class Test {

    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        String a = "123testes1233iambeginnerplshelp123";
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
        for (int i=0; i<a.length()-1; i++) {
            while (i<a.length()-1 && !(!isNumber(a.charAt(i)) && isNumber(a.charAt(i+1)))) {
                sb.append(a.substring(i,i+1));
                i++;
            }
            sb.append(a.substring(i,i+1));
            System.out.println(sb.toString());
            sb.setLength(0);
        }

    }

    private static boolean isNumber (char c) {
        return ((int)c >=48) && ((int)c <= 57);
    }

}
```

Comment: This is definitely how you should do it. My only recommendation is append '\n' instead of printing every line and setting length to 0. Then you can do one large print afterwards. You should also use StringBuilder over StringBuffer.

Answer (score 0):

my solution

```
public StringSplitNum(){ 
    String someString = "123testes1233iambeginnerplshelp123abc";
    String regex = "((?<=[a-zA-Z])(?=[0-9]))|((?<=[0-9])(?=[a-zA-Z]))";
    List arr = Arrays.asList(someString.split(regex));
    for(int i=0; i< arr.size();i+=2){
    System.out.println(arr.get(i)+ " " + arr.get(i+1));
}
```